# Surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show $\exists$ a surjective homomorphism $\phi:D_8 \rightarrow C_2 \times C_2$

I have worked out  that $\langle\rho^2\rangle$ $\triangleleft$ $ D_8$ and that

$\displaystyle \frac{D_8}{\langle\rho^2\rangle} \cong C_2 \times C_2$

The solution is as follows:
[image]

I do not follow the part highlighted in green.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply indicating the quotient map $D_8\to D_8/\langle \rho^2\rangle \cong C_2\times C_2$.

Quotient maps are clearly homomorphisms and surjective, so with the identification $D_8/\langle \rho^2\rangle \cong C_2\times C_2$, we get the map we want.

Comment: So if I define $\phi:D_8 \rightarrow D_8/\langle \rho^2\rangle$, I get that $\phi$ is a homomorphism and $ker\phi= <{\rho}^2> \implies D_8/\langle \rho^2\rangle \cong Im \phi$ so does this imply $Im \phi=C_2 \times C_2$?

Comment: It implies that $Im\phi \cong C_2\times C_2$, so composing $\phi$ with the isomorphsim $\psi: D_8/\langle \rho^2\rangle \cong C_2\times C_2$ gives the homomorphsim you want.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to see the actual homomorphism. We have:

$N = \{e,\rho^2\}$. Let's look at the right cosets (we already have $N$, the identity of $D_8/N$):

$N\rho = \{\rho,\rho^3\}$ (this is also $N\rho^3$).

$N\sigma = \{\sigma, \sigma\rho^2\}$ (obviously, this is also $N\sigma\rho^2$ -note $\rho^2$ commutes with $\sigma)$.

$N\sigma\rho = \{\sigma\rho, \sigma\rho^3\}$ (= $N\sigma\rho^3$).

So, explicitly:

$\phi(e) = \phi(\rho^2) = N$

$\phi(\rho) = \phi(\rho^3) = N\rho$

$\phi(\sigma) = \phi(\sigma\rho^2) = N\sigma$

$\phi(\sigma\rho) = \phi(\sigma\rho^3) = N\sigma\rho$.

---

Perhaps it isn't clear this is (isomorphic to) $C_2 \times C_2$. But we can easily verify:

$N\rho N\rho = N\rho^2 = N$ (the identity).

$N\sigma N\sigma = N$

$N\sigma\rho N\sigma\rho = N(\sigma\rho)^2 = N$, so every non-identity element has order $2$.

We have $\{N, N\rho\} \cong C_2$ (as every group of order $2$ is), and $\{N,N\sigma\} \cong C_2$.

As both of these are subgroups of index $2$ in $\phi(D_8)$, they are normal, and:

$\{N,N\rho\} \cap \{N,N\sigma\} = \{N\}$, so $\phi(D_8) = \{N,N\rho\}\{N,N\sigma\}$ (the internal direct product of these subgroups), which and thus isomorphic to $\{N,N\rho\} \times \{N,N\sigma\} \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

If we "re-label" the cosets $\{E,R,S,SR\}$, we get something that looks more like the "usual" Klein 4-group. Be aware that we are typically only concerned with identifying groups "up to isomorphism", so it is somewhat of an abuse of notation to state:

$\text{im }\phi = C_2 \times C_2$.